# Protect the react routes with two different layouts childrens

Tags: reactjs, routes, protected

I am protecting the routes and making sure the if no route found or if the user does not loggedin, then redirects the user to login page. I have tried a lot solutions but nothing work for me.I have tried with the variable but I got nothing, the user does not navigate to login screen if const a !== 'admin',
All I wanted if const a === 'admin' then navigate to routes and if no route found then navigate to '/' path and if const a !== 'admin' then navigate to '/login'
App.js code

```
    enter code hereimport { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { CssBaseline, StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material';

// routing
// import Routes from 'routes';

// defaultTheme
import themes from 'themes';

// project imports
import NavigationScroll from 'layout/NavigationScroll';

// Alert toastify
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainLayout from './layout/MainLayout';
import AuthLayout from './layout/MinimalLayout';
import DashboardDefault from './views/dashboard/Default';
import Orders from './views/pages/orders/orders';
import MenuPage from './views/pages/Menu/Menu';
import PromoCodesPage from './views/pages/promocodes/PromoCodes';
import LoginPage from './views/pages/authentication/authentication3/Login3';
// ==============================|| APP ||============================== //

const App = () => {
    const customization = useSelector((state) => state.customization);
    const a = 'admin';

    return (
        <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
            <ToastContainer />
            <ThemeProvider theme={themes(customization)}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <NavigationScroll>
                    <Routes>
                        {a === 'admin' ? (
                            <Route path="/" element={<MainLayout />}>
                                <Route path="/" element={<DashboardDefault />} />
                                <Route path="/dashboard/default" element={<DashboardDefault />} />
                                <Route path="/orders" element={<Orders />} />

                                <Route path="/menu" element={<MenuPage />} />

                                <Route path="/promocodes" element={<PromoCodesPage />} />
                            </Route>
                        ) : (
                            <Route path="/" element={<AuthLayout />}>
                                <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
                            </Route>
                        )}
                    </Routes>
                </NavigationScroll>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </StyledEngineProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Ok, here you have deinfed the routes but where is the redirect code. You should redirect users to the route defined earlier.

Comment: Something like if a  ! == admin { redirect to login page }

Comment: I have tried that and then I have accessd the / path then it shows blank screen

Comment: Debug for few more hours, you know the concept, you will learn a lot of helpful fundas and also get your code running. Just saying :) :)